# Approach to design database tables

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, database-design, database-schema

I am new here as well as new in coding. I always get confused when it comes to database designing. Let me try to explain this.

If I need to create a functionality like this (Stackoverflow) website, More specific If I just want simple Question (posting, upvote, downvote) and Answer(posting, upvote, downvote) feature in my website I could follow two approaches.

> First

- create a table `question` in which I will save question.
- create a table `votes` in which I will save votes(up and down).
- To fetch a question will need to join these two table and get the question and there votes(up and down)

> Second

- Create a table `question` in which I will save question and **votes count(tow more column to store count up and down votes)**
- Create a table `votes` in which I will save votes(up and down).
- This time we can get the data from one tablw without `join`.

I always want to know which one I should use.

**I know that in first approach we need to put more joins if we add more feature like (Share,View,Answer,etc).**

**And if i used second approach we need to take care of consistency and we also need to insert more times as in first approach.**

I don't know someone who can answer this. That's why i am asking my question here.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: This is probably better off on [Programmers StackExchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) than here.

Comment: you're asking for opinions. "clean" design demands the first option. practical/realworld considerastions point at the second. if you end up having a popular system with zillions of questions and gazillions of votes, having to count(*) the votes every time a question is viewed will be a massive drain on system resources. e.g. caching the vote counts in the question record makes sense for "big" systems, but the maintenance overhead will only be worthwhile if/when the system does become "big".

Comment: @MarcB exactly thanks for your response sir  :)

Comment: You've tagged 2 relational databases.  You use [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) to create relations for a relational database.

Comment: @Munir when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will learn a lot by looking at the Stack Exchange Data Explorer.

> https://data.stackexchange.com/

In addition to seeing the schema and being able to type interactive queries, you can view, execute, and modify the excellent library of useful queries other people have contributed.

It's a wonderful way to learn from a real-world site.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your time and answer :)